# TLS 1.3 Cipher Suites: authentication algorithm unspecified?

Tags: tls, cipher-selection

I was looking at Cipher Suites indicated on [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) and I noticed something, here is a result for google.com (for instance):

[image: SSLLabs Cipher Suites — google.com server]

With TLS 1.2, examples of Cipher Suites are:

- *TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256*: in which I understand that the server authentication part is done using *ECDSA*, the session ephemeral key is established using *ECDHE*, the symmetric encryption algorithm is *AES_128_GCM* and the message authentication is using *SHA256*
- *TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256*: in which the difference is that the server authentication is performed using *RSA*

First, **is that interpretation correct**?

Now, with TLS 1.3 I see Cipher Suites like *TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256* which do not mention a public/private key algorithm (e.g. *RSA*, *ECDSA*).

**What is the server authentication algorithm used in this case and why is it not specified in the Cipher Suite?**

Comment: Mostly dupe https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/257776/how-are-key-exchange-and-signature-algorithms-negotiated-in-tls-1-3

Answer (score 3):

From "[Major Differences from TLS 1.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-1.2)" in the RFC:

> The cipher suite concept has been changed to
> separate the authentication and key exchange mechanisms from the
> record protection algorithm (including secret key length) and a
> hash to be used with both the key derivation function and
> handshake message authentication code (MAC)

See "[Protocol Overview](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-2)" section of RFC for overview.

See "[Cryptographic Negotiation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-4.1.1)" subsection of Handshake section of the RFC about the TLS handshake.

The FFDHE was changed to only support named groups (no custom groups like those produced by `openssl dhparam`), but in practice nobody uses FFDHE, so you get to specify X25519 or NISP P-256, P-384, P-521.
See "[Supported Groups Extension](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#appendix-B.3.1.4)" section of the RFC for supported values.

The signatures used in practice are ECDSA with NIST P-256 and RSA PKCS#1 v1.5 and RSASSA-PSS. TLS1.3 changed the requirement to produce RSASSA-PSS signature using the private key of the end-entity certificate if the public key is of RSA type (regardless of the signatures in the certificates themselves).
See "[Signature Algorithm Extension](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#appendix-B.3.1.3)" section of the RFC for supported values.